# Windows dotNet application security

Tags: windows, .net, winforms, консоль, exe

They sent me a file with a .rar extension and I extracted it and launched the application there, it started but when I wanted to click on View images the following error appeared [image: as in the picture]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score -1):

Пожалуйста, пишите на русском. В ошибке написано, что нужно указать в реестре `InstallRoot`.

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework` - Тут его можно найти.

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework` - сюда его нужно вставить.

Если не найден файл `InstallRoot` - создай его